# How to repent after breaking a fast by masturbation?

Tags: sawm, kaffarah

I have committed a sin (Masturbate) that invalidated my fast. Can you please advice on how to repent and what actions I should do for my repentance to be valid?

I am 16 years old and can't afford to feed 60 people. Please recommend an alternative!

Comment: I know that masturbating is haram but please font judge and tell me what to do

Comment: Please repent to Allah swt first and true repentance means that you would not do that again also see this http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2012/08/14/is-expiation-required-for-masturbating-while-fasting/

Answer (score 2):

If you broke a fast during Ramadan by masturbating, then you must make up that fast by fasting a day after the month of Ramadan. You should also repent to Allah Almighty and seek his forgiveness. Do not loss hope in Allah's mercy. Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):

> “Say: O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair
>   not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is
>   Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.” [Qur'an 39:53]

Answer (score 1):

Praise be to Allah
Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):

“And those who, when they have committed fahishah (illegal sexual intercourse) or wronged themselves with evil, remember Allah and ask forgiveness for their sins; — and none can forgive sins but Allah — and do not persist in what (wrong) they have done, while they know.
For such, the reward is forgiveness from their Lord, and Gardens with rivers flowing underneath (Paradise), wherein they shall abide forever. How excellent is this reward for the doers (who do righteous deeds according to Allah’s orders).

[3:135-136]

Ibn Katheer said:

The words “and do not persist in what (wrong) they have done” mean: they repent from their sins and quickly turn to Allah, and they do not persist in their sin, rather they give it up, and if they do it again they repent to Him. Tafseer Ibn Katheer.

Answer (score 0):

Repent , do not do it again ever,  either in Ramadan or not, then fast as many days as you broke.  If it was in the past year or prior, then it is better to feed one poor human (maskeen) for each day you broke.